# Div containing a row of div are wrapping instead of overflowing

Tags: javascript, html

I am using JavaScript to insert  elements inside a container div:

```
<tr>
    <td align="left">
    &nbsp;</td>
    <td  style="background-color:#5D7B9D">
        <div id="headerMasterDiv">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 18px; height: 18px;">
    &nbsp;</td>
</tr>

for (var i=0; i < len; i++ ) 
{

    id = "headerColumn_" + i.toString();
    width = columnWidths[i];
    text = columnTexts[i];
    html = " <div id=\""+id+"\" class=\"test\">"+text+"</div> ";
    header.innerHTML += html;
}
```

However I would like the inner  to overflow, so I can activate an horizontal scrollbar. But instead they are wrapping:

[image: div wrapping]

Tx.

Comment: This looks like tabular data. Why not use a nested table?

Comment: Try `white-space: nowrap` on the container (`#headerMasterDiv`).

Comment: You are also using fixed widths. Remove the fixed width to make it expand with the text.

Comment: asp.net GridView does not keep the header showing if you scrolldown. This was fixed by a js script which remove the header table, and insert it into an empty place holder which does not scroll (removeChild, appendChild). This does not work anymore with IE11, the moved table resize on content so the width dont match the data rows size. Using <div> we can resize them the way we need.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `overflow:auto` to your div.

In the test class :

```
.test 
{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Or inline style, i suggest using quot and double quot it's more readable :

```
 ' <div id="'+id+'" class="test" style="overflow:auto">'+text+'</div> ';
```